# How to write QAbstractItemModel as formatted text?

Tags: c++, qt, formatting, string-formatting, qabstractitemmodel

I have a filled QAbstractItemModel object, e.g.:

```
level_1 (root TreeItem)
..+------> level_2_0
.............+------> level_2_0_0
.............+------> level_2_0_1
.............+------> level_2_0_2
..+------> level_2_1
.............+------> level_2_1_0
.............+------> level_2_1_1
```

I would like to write formatted output like:

```
#include "level_1"

[name="level_2_0"]
{
value1 : "level_2_0_0";
value2 : "level_2_0_1";
value3 : "level_2_0_2";
}

[name="level_2_1"]
{
value1 : "level_2_1_0";
value2 : "level_2_1_1";
}
```

How can I make this professional? When I have the token level_2_0 I have to wait for its three children, to close the "}" bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a depth-first search. You traverse the tree by going to the first node (level_2_0 in your case), then going to all its children (level_2_0_n), then going to the next child of your root (level_2_1) etc...

You can find pseudocode and a better explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search